# How to avoid SQL statements spreading everywhere in your app?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a medium-sized app written in Ruby, which makes pretty heavy use of a RDBMS. As our code grows, I found the ugly SQL statements are spreading to all modules and methods in my app and embedded in many application logic. I am not sure if this is bad, however, my gut tells me this is quite ugly...

So generally in any languages, how do you manage your SQL statements? Or do you think it is harmful for maintainibility to let many SQL statements embedded in the application logic? Why or why not?

Thanks.

Comment: In ColdFusion I write them where I need them and don't worry about it.  In .net I use OOP and SPs.   I write classes in a data access layer that call the SPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a language for accessing databases.  Often, it gets confused as being the API into the data store for a larger application.  In fact, you should design a real API between the data store and the app.

The means several things.

For accessing data stored in tables, you want to go through views in the database, rather than directly access the tables.

For data modification steps, you want to wrap `insert`/`update`/`delete` in stored procedures.  This has secondary benefits, where you can handle constraints and triggers in the stored procedure and better log what is happening.

For security, you want to include database security as part of your security architecture.  Giving all users full access may not be the best approach.

Unfortunately, it is easy to write a simple app that uses a database directly, whether in java or ruby or VBA or whatever.  This grows into a bigger app, and then the maintenance problems arise.

I would suggest an incremental approach to fixing this.  Go through the code and create views where you have nasty select statements.  You'll probably find you need many fewer views than selects (the views can be re-used -- a good thing).

Find places where code is being modified, and change these to stored procedures.  I always return status from the stored procedure for error checking and put log information into a table called someting like `splog` or `_spcalls`.

If you want to limit permissions for different users of your app, then you might be interested in [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html).

Leaving the raw SQL statements in the code is a problem.  Just wait until you want to rename a column and you have to find all the places where this breaks the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not optimal - maintenance becomes a nightmare; it's hard to forecast and determine which code must change when underlying DB changes occur.  This is why it is good practice to create a data access layer (DAL) to encapsulate CRUD operations from the application logic.  There is often an business logic layer (BLL) between the application logic and DAL to enforce business rules/logic.

Google "data access layer" "business logic layer" and even "n-tier architecture" to learn more.

Comment: Is these kind of abstraction fairly widely-used? For example, does web developers (or main stream web frameworks) usually abstract the DB stuff in this way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the SQL statements littered around your application logic, maybe consider implementing them as Stored Procedures?

That way you will only be including the procedure name and any parameters that need to be passed to it in your code.

It has other benefits too, a common one being easier to re-use in multiple files.

There is much debate about speed and security of Stored Procedure and you will never get a definitive answer about that so I won't even open that can of worms.

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot stored procedures. Though I'm not really experienced in SQL, I have seen (and probably also written) many buggy and scary SP. So I think I won't go with it. +1 for pointing out SP anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do this with Java:  Create a class that encapsulates all access to the database.  Add a method to the class for each query you need to run.

The answer for ruby will be similar to this.

Comment: Not really.  This class is the facade to the database.  Actually implementation of the queries can be in any number of classes.  Users of the database only see the facade.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture of your application but a simple solution is to keep each sql in a file, qry.sql. For each Ruby module (or whatever is used in Ruby to aggregate related code) you can keep a folder SQL with these files. So, the collection of SQL folder/files form the data access layer of your application. The Ruby code provides the business layer. If your data model changes (field names, etc), you can do greps to identify the sql files that need changes. Anyway, definitely separate SQL from your logic code.